# Can Adobe AIR display SVG?

Tags: air, svg

I see that Adobe AIR uses WebKit as its render and I see that WebKit (at least the most current build) has some SVG support. Does this mean (and has anyone specifically tried) that an Adobe AIR application could render SVG on an HTML page?

Comment: read that HTML page, parse SVG element, render it with [Degrapha (a declarative open source graphics framework)](http://www.degrafa.org/) that supports [SVG (example vith source)](http://www.degrafa.org/source/Car/Car.html)

Comment: Any update on SVG support in 2019?

Answer (score 4):

On the offchance that it's helpful (and that you don't already know), Flex can embed SVG at <s>runtime</s> compile time, which effectively converts it to SWF format and embeds it as a resource.

```
[Embed(source="assets/frog.svg")]
[Bindable]
public var SvgAsset:Class;
```

More info at Adobe's [embedding assets article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/embedding_assets/#EmbeddingSvgFiles).

Comment: you mean that it can embed SVG at *compile* time.

Answer (score 3):

If ActionScript 2: use the **com.itechnica.svg** (PathToArray) library to load SVGs at SWF runtime and display them *(uses XML for SVG parsing)*:

[Using **SVG Path Data** in Flash](http://flash-creations.com/notes/sample_svgtoflash.php), Download button on the **right pane.**

---

If ActionScript 3: use the  **com.zavoo.svg** (SvgPath) library to load SVGs at SWF runtime and display them *(uses RegExp for SVG parsing)*:

[Source code for **SvgLoad** and **SvgDraw**](http://labs.zavoo.com/content/flex/DrawSvg/srcview/index.html), Download button on the **bottom-left.**

Answer (score 2):

**No**, according to the Adobe AIR Developer Center article [What's new about HTML, HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript in AIR 2.5?](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/articles/air_and_webkit.html).

> **SVG**
>
> Another feature that has received
>   a great deal of interest lately is
>   support for SVG. While present in
>   WebKit, the current version of Adobe
>   AIR does not support SVG.
>
> The main reason for not including it
>   was runtime size concerns (adding it
>   would have increased the runtime size
>   by 15 to 20 percent). Initially, the
>   main pain-points regarding AIR were
>   the size of the runtime, integration
>   with the operating system and native
>   APIs, support for the  tag and
>   new CSS properties, and JavaScript
>   performance. These priorities, coupled
>   with a trend toward reduced interest
>   in SVG graphics, led to SVG support
>   not being included in the current
>   version of Adobe AIR.
>
> However, the renewed interest in rich
>   JavaScript applications powered by
>   HTML5 canvas and faster JavaScript
>   engines increased the number of
>   requests for scriptable vector
>   graphics via SVG. Thus, adding support
>   for SVG graphics may be considered for
>   the next version of AIR.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AIR can only support SVG once Adobe updates their version of WebKit (AIR's HTML rendering engine) and enables the SVG support within their version of WebKit. Might be a business decision not to (ie Flash).